# Eclipse showing weird Symbols instead of Text

Tags: eclipse

My Eclipse IDE is showing weird Symbols I don't understand why , it just show weird symbols instead of Text ,

[image: here is the image of my situation]

Comment: Looks a fonts problem to me, what OS is that?

Comment: It is a problem with the fonts on your system, see the duplicate